# Free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions match at some point

Tags: group-actions, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

I have in front of me a proof of this lemma:

> If $f$ and $g$ are free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions on $S^1$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x \in S^1$.

A $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on the unit circle $S^1$ is a homeomorphism $f \;:\; S^1 \rightarrow S^1$
such that $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in S^1$;
and $f$ is free if $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in S^1$.

The proof (in a paper I'm refereeing) is clear but somewhat laborious. It would be nice to
either have a succinct proof, or a reference, rather than a detailed proof from first principles.
Has anyone seen this before?  Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why this false notation, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/n$, is so common.

Comment: What do you mean by "false notation"? For many places it is the one true notation, and saying "zee-p" is a lot easier than "zee-mod-p-zee", which has only become popular in the last twenty years, probably due to bourbakist influence...

Comment: @Martin: I agree with Igor, what's a "false notation"? A notation is a notation, once it's generally agreed upon it's not false. If anything the notation ℤ/n is a bad one IMO. If you want to be precise then you should write something like $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ or ℤ/nℤ. The latter is fairly common but I like $\mathbb Z_n$ just fine.

Comment: How could ${\mathbf Z}/n$ be considered bad while ${\mathbf Z}_n$ is fine?  They both have the same amount of content. (I know what you mean about ${\mathbf Z}/n{\mathbf Z}$ being more precise, but if you can handle the idea of writing ${\mathbf Z}_n$ then ${\mathbf Z}/n$ should be okay too.)

Comment: @ KConrad: This is a matter of taste but in my opinion there is a difference between these two notations. $\mathbb Z/n$ is trying to say that it's $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ (or $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$) but it's doing it half-way and a result looks like a bad mathematical formula. I personally don't like such notations and would never use it.

$\mathbb Z_n$ does not try to do that. Here $n$ is simply the index in the natural list of cyclic groups much like $\pi_n(X)$ or $H_n(X)$.

Comment: @Vitali Kapovitch: I would not personally call it 'false' but I think what is true is that there is not extension of this meaning of the notation or equivalently it is no specialization of a more general notation. While indeed there is a standard general notation for the same thing *and* $Z_n$ in other meanings (completion, localisation) has extension / is a special case. So that I find it  a mildly unfortunate notation of integers modulo n. 

Comment: Sorry for still one more comment (I delte on redundant one in exchange): I also find Z/n mildy unfortunate. To add still somethings else I vaguely remember Fuchs uses Z(n).

Comment: It seemed to me at some point, probably when I was in grad school (late fifties and early sixties) that the topologists used the notation ${\mathbb{Z}}_n$ while we number-theorists used the notations ${\mathbb{Z}}/n$ or ${\mathbb{Z}}/(n)$ or ${\mathbb{Z}}/n{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Perhaps the following is an answer to Martin's original question (somewhat backed up by some of the somments): The notation $Z_n$ for integers modulo n is fine and natural if and only if one does not deal with $Z_n$ in its others meanings (on a regular basis).

Comment: It may be related in several ways to the compact vs quasi-compact debate. 

Comment: The notation $A_p$ is already overloaded (localization at an element, localization at a prime ideal, or even for its adic completion). On the other hand, the meaning of $A/pA$, or for short $A/p$, is unambiguous. I also agree with quid. @Joseph: Sorry for this offtopic discussion.

Comment: @quid: On p. 14 of Fuchs's "Infinite Abelian Groups, Vol. 1", visible on Google books, he writes $Z(m)$ for the additive group of integers mod $m$. I don't think that notation extended beyond the community of infinite abelian group theorists.

Comment: @Martin: No problem! The issue you raised is more interesting than my original question! :-) 

Answer (score 13):

we can clearly assume that $f(z)=-z$ in the standard metric on $S^1\subset \mathbb C$ (as we can assume that $f$ is isometric with respect to some Riemannnian metric on $S^1$). Then $g(z)=z\cdot e^{i\alpha(z)}$ with $0<\alpha(z)<2\pi$. If $\alpha(z_0)<\pi$ then $\alpha(g(z_0))>\pi$ and there is a point $z_1$ with $\alpha(z_1)=\pi$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Vitali: Thanks!!!  And apologies re $\mathbb{Z}^2$ vs. $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Is it completely clear that we can choose $\alpha$ to be continuous?

Comment: @ Martin: yes, it's completely clear. $i\alpha(z)=log(\frac{g(z)}{z})$ and its branch  is well defined since $g$ is is fixed point free.