# History of the notation $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: ho.history-overview

This question was motivated by Martin's comment in [Free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions match at some point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81896/free-mathbbz-2-actions-match-at-some-point)

When was the notation $\mathbb Z_n$ introduced for $n$-adic integers and by whom?  When was it introduced for integers modulo $n$ and by whom?

I tried searching on Google without much luck.

**Added**. Martin brings up the related point when was the subscript notation $A_f$ introduced for localizing a ring at the monoid generated by $f$ (which is a third possible interpretation of $\mathbb Z_n$)?

Comment: It is pretty common to denote the cyclic group of order $n$ by $C_n\dots$

Comment: I looked in Hensel's original book Theorie der Algebraischen Zahlen and he writes ${\mathbf Q}_p$ as $K(p)$ and, as far as I could tell, he has no specific notation for $p$-adic integers. He just refers to them when needed with the words "$p$-adic integers" (in German). In Hasse's book Number Theory the $p$-adic numbers are $P_p$ and the $p$-adic integers are $\Gamma_p$.

Comment: Borevich-Shafarevich's book "Number Theory" (1960s) denotes the $p$-adic integers as $O_p$, $p$-adic numbers as $R_p$ (since they write $R$ for the rational numbers). Dwork's paper on rationality of the zeta-function (Amer. J. Math 1960) denotes $p$-adic numbers as $Q'$ and $p$-adic integers as ${\mathfrak O}'$. Lubin's paper on formal groups (Ann. Math. 80, 1964) uses ${\mathbf Z}_p$ for the $p$-adic integers and ${\mathbf Q}_p$ for the $p$-adic numbers. Someone should look at the first edition of Serre's Corps Locaux (1962).

Comment: Better yet, look at Serre's Collected Works.

Comment: I think people tend to use the $C_n$ notation when they are thinking of a cyclic group multiplicatively. 

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: It is also pretty frequent for additive cyclic groups. But a cyclic group with n elements is 'strictly less' than the integers modulo n. (The later naturally being a unitary ring while for the former there is no natural multiplication; except for 1 and 2.) 

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: I think it'd be more accurate to say $C_n$ is a notation for the cyclic group *abstractly* (using multiplication for the group law notation, as usual in abstract groups) rather than the cyclic group multiplicatively, because many people might want to write that as $\mu_n$.

Comment: @KConrad,  you said what I meant better than me. 

Comment: @quid, excellent point. 

Comment: I have the 1968 edition of Corps Locaux, which is a photographic reproduction of the first edition. Serre Uses ${\mathbf{Q}}_p$ for the $p$-adic numbers, and ${\mathbf{Z}}_p$ for their integers. I'm pretty sure that I learned this notation from Lang, in  course I took with him at Columbia, in 1956-57.

Comment: It was only after Bourbaki that the notation ${\bf Q}$ (resp.~${\bf Z}$) got universally adopted for the field of rational numbers (resp. for its ring of integers).  I believe that the notation ${\bf Z}_p$, ${\bf Q}_p$ originates with Bourbaki.

Comment: One should be careful to distiguish ${\bb Z}$ from ${\Bbb Z}$, i.e., the bold font from the “blackboard bold” font.  Bourbaki always used the bold font in his books.  I wonder who introduced the “blackboard bold” font in printed texts and why.  See this discussion in comp.text.tex: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/55bd03b808263cee/6300d1a3a394ccb9

Comment: Somewhat into the opposite direction of Dimiti Pavlov I would like to argue that IMO  Hasse's notation recalled by KConrad is *this* notation (first version appeared 1950; I cannot check whether it is alos there but I assume this was not changed). My point of view is that the *key point* is to used the p (and then valuation, the ideal yielding the valuation) as a *subscript* to the ring/field (as opposed to in parenthesis as in earlier writings in particular the mentioned Hensel and this seesm to have been common early 20th cent like Ostrowski, Kurschak). 

Comment: @Benjamin: Would you mind to include the localization to your question? The funny thing is that there are people who write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for the cyclic group of order $n$, $A_f$ for the localization of a ring by an element $f$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]$ for the special case $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $f=n$. Isn't this hilarious?

Comment: @Martin: The localization of ${\mathbf Z}$ at a prime $p$ would be denoted ${\mathbf Z}_{(p)}$ by people who use ${\mathbf Z}_p$ for $p$-adic integers. That a concrete notation may not faithfully reflect the abstract notation is also visible in geometry, where $M^n$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold but nobody writes $n$-dimensional Euclidean space as $({\mathbf R}^n)^n$.

Comment: I think quid is right: the person who first used $p$ as a subscript for completion should be considered the one who introduced this notation, even if it was long before the integers or rationals were written their current way. In Hasse's 1st paper on quad. forms over ${\mathbf Q}$ and the $p$-adics (Crelle 152 (1923)) he writes ${\mathbf Q}$ as $K(1)$, ${\mathbf Q}_p$ as $K(p)$ (just like Hensel), and ${\mathbf Z}$ as $R(1)$. In Hasse's paper on local class field theory (Crelle 162 (1930)) he writes the ${\mathfrak p}$-adic completion of a number field $k$ as $\overline{k}$. [contd...]

Comment: In the Brauer--Hasse--Noether paper on central simple algebras over number fields (Crelle 167 (1932)) the ${\mathfrak p}$-adic completion of a number field $\Omega$ is denoted $\Omega_{{\mathfrak p}}$. So that puts the introduction of this notation to 1932 or earlier. 

Comment: I am not sure if inventing completion as a subscript is quite equivalent to using $\mathbb Z_n$ for $n$-adic integers because it is possible (although so far this question has produced no answers in this direction) that $\mathbb Z_n$ was already in use for the ring of integers modulo $n$. If this was the case (to be determined) then deciding that the completion notation takes precedence over the existing notation for integers modulo $n$ would be a bold decision.  

Comment: In a paper on $p$-adic division algebras (Math. Annalen 104 (1931), 495--534), Hasse writes the ${\mathfrak p}$-adic completion of a number field $K$ as $K_{\mathfrak p}$ (p. 497). 

Comment: @Benjamin: figuring out when each notation was first used is interesting!  

Comment: Math geekiness at its finest! :)


Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: IMO todays questions what is good practise for notation should not mainly be decided along the lines of historical precedence. As I indirectly said in the linked question, when used for integers modulo n this notation is AFAIK completely localised.  
And, there are (standrad) alternatives that fit into a bigger picture of notation. And, it clashes with something else (ok, this is symmetric). And, finally, it puts relevant information into a subscript (this is less symmetric). So it might not be 'false' but IMO it is 'wrong' to use it (not to be read too drastically).   

Comment: Physicists tend to write $Z_n$ for the cyclic group of order $n$, never mind $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Did they diverge from mathematicians at some point, or perhaps mathematicians switched notation and the physicists just kept using the old notation?

Comment: I believe notation can either be good or bad, clear or unclear. I am not sure what other adjectives are relevant. For instance, I would regard $\mathbb Z_n$ as not very good notation for any of its three meanings. The subscript notation for localization at a set $S$ is unclear.  The notation $A[S^{-1}]$ is much clearer. Only historical precedent leaves $A_S$ as the default.  Using a subscript for completion again is intuitive. Standard notation for power series could instead be generalized.

Comment: Change the intuitive above for unintuitive. 

Comment: I completely agree that the localisation-situation is not nice at all and the $S^{-1} A$ is clearer:
let $P$ be a prime ideal, what is $A_P$, $(A \setminus P)^{-1}A$ or $P^{-1}A$ ... terrible. For the completion one might want to keep in mind that if one has just has some valuation $v$ on a field $K$ and no t the uniformizing element one can still write `$K_v$`.
For me the main issue is really internal consistency. If it were common to write `$R_P$` for R modulo P, the situation would change. But AFAIK noone does this. And, there also in view of Jeff Harvey's remark the usage of...


Comment: ...this notation for integers modulo n has the additional issue of confounding the distinction betwenn this ring(!) and an (abstact) cyclic group. So if somebody used `$Z_n$`, really standard Z, instead of `$C_n$` for a abstract cyclic group I think this is less problematic (to the extent this can be problematic at all). 

For the notation itself I agree regarding the adjectives, but regarding whether one uses the one or the other I think there can be a right and wrong; albeit definitely only a subjective one that can also change with context. 

Comment: It seems Birkhoff and MacLane used $\mathbf Z_n$ to denote the set $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ with the ring structure we know and love.  Although nowadays we tend to identify isomorphic rings, it would not surprise me if once upon a time the notation $\mathbf Z_n$ (or  its pre-Z versions) meant the above realization of this ring and I could imagine a textbook proving $\mathbf Z_n\cong \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. 

Answer (score 11):

I fished around in Google scholar and found so many examples that I don't feel like listing any of the links.  Nonetheless, a clear picture emerges of an answer that I found a bit surprising:  The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the $p$-adic integers evolved in three separate parts.  I should also explain that the real science of etymology is about the evolution of words or notation, not just "when did it first happen".

The subscript notation not only for the $p$-adic integers, but more generally for $p$-adic completions, already appears in several papers in the 1930s and 1940s.  For instance Carl Ludwig Siegel says in 1941, "$R$ is the field of rational numbers, $R_p$ the field of $p$-adic numbers, where $p$ denotes any prime number, $R_\infty$ the field of real numbers; moreover $J$ is the ring of integral numbers and $J_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers".  Of course, no one would use this notation today!

The use of $Z$ for the integers has a semi-separate history.  I even found an old paper, but more recent than this one by Siegel, that used $Z$ for the integers but $R$ for the $p$-adic integers, with no subscript.

Generally the notation for $p$-adic integers and $p$-adic numbers standardized at $Z_p$ and $Q_p$ in the 1950s.  Quite possibly Bourbaki, Algebra, deserves credit for standardizing $Z$ and $Q$ for integers and rationals.

Blackboard bold notation ($\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$) came last, at least in print.  Despite its name, it's no longer obvious to me that blackboard bold actually first came from blackboards or from typewriters.  It's sometimes also credited to Bourbaki, but this seems to be wrong.  There is a historical account by Lee Rudolph (in comp.text.tex) that credits certain typewriter models in the 1960s for producing blackboard bold typography for the integers, etc. If that is where it started, then the notation seemed to catch on fairly quickly, although there were holdouts that used ordinary bold for decades after that.  (But, before blackboard bold was fashionable, it wasn't even standard to make the set of integers bold $\mathbf{Z}$ instead of just $Z$.)

As an aside, the collision of notation between the $p$-adic integers and the integers mod $p$ is unfortunate.  I really prefer to write $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for the integers mod $n$, because it is then written exactly as it reads.  Also, partly since it is such a commonly used object, I see no need for extra parentheses, or an extra $\mathbb{Z}$, and certainly just using an $n$ subscript is bad.  I'm optimistic that this notation is the way of the future and it would be an interesting separate question in history of notation.

(Sorry, I didn't see the entire string of comments before I wrote all of this.  The comments make most of these remarks, but it seems useful to combine them into one historical summary.)

Comment: Did you see anything indicating when some for of Z subscript n appeared (blackboard or not) for integers mod n?  The comments above seemed to have already landed the subscript notation for completions at the door of Hasse in the thirties.

Comment: One should check what notation, if any, van der Waerden used in Moderne Algebra (1930) for the integers mod $n$ since whatever convention he chose influenced the next generations in algebra but not necessarily other parts of mathematics. (Incidentally, in his book Number Theory (1950), Hasse wrote $Z_\infty$ for the complex numbers.) 

Comment: I found a paper by one John Moore (1957) that uses $Z_n$ for integers mod $n$ and $Z^p$ for $p$-adic integers.  So that's one solution, apparently obsolete, for the collision-of-notation problem.  Now I see a couple of other papers in the 1950s.  It seems that the standard of $Z$ for the integers, which appeared in that period, swept in the collision of notation immediately and unintentionally.  Nakayama (1957) writes $Z(p)$ for $\mathbb{Z}/p$, integers mod $p$, while Floyd (1951) writes $I_p$ for the same.

Comment: Greg: It's okay not to give links, but could you indicate the journal and not just the year? It makes it easier to check things.

Comment: Sorry,

Nakayama: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.nmj/1118799937

Moore: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC528465/pdf/pnas00696-0053.pdf

Floyd: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1952-072-01/S0002-9947-1952-0046039-4/S0002-9947-1952-0046039-4.pdf

Comment: Maybe you could add your Moore, Floyd references into your answer so that it is more visible. 